# How to access a databound DataGridView's DataSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, dataset

I am building a data-driven WinForms application in C# using a PostgreSQL database. Currently I am populating my two DataGridViews as follows.

I have a class in which I plan on doing all of my database-related work - get data from the database, add update and delete data in the database tables, etc. That class currently looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using Npgsql;

namespace Test_XRef_Tool.Xref_Test
{
    public class Db
    {
        private string connString = String.Format("Server = localhost; Port = 5432; Database = dvdrental; User Id = userid; Password = password;");

        // Used to retrieve data for population of controls (DGVs, CBOs, etc)
        public DataTable GetData(string selectQuery)
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, conn);
                conn.Close();

                da.Fill(ds);
                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And on my Form1 class I'm populating two DGVs. The code to populate them looks like this:

```
Db categoriesData = new Db();
dgvCategories.DataSource = categoriesData.GetData("SELECT * FROM actor");

Db defaultsData = new Db();
dgvDefaults.DataSource = defaultsData.GetData("SELECT * FROM film");
```

This all works fine to populate the DGVs, but I realized that during user-editing of the DGVs and various other operations I plan on doing in the program, I need access to the DGV's datasource - prior to any changes made to the DGV cells.

How do I do that? My thought is that I need to create some sort of object or variable on the Form1 class that will hold the current state of the DGV's data, but I can't figure out how to do that - if that's even the right way to do this.

Comment: `dgvCategories.DataSource as DataTable`. You can have a DataTable field and maybe also keep the DataAdapter, you'll probably need it (if you setup its Commands). If you need  to bind other Controls, use a BindingSource as the DataSource of your DGV and the source of other controls DataBindings (the DataSource of the BindingSource is of course your DataTable).

Answer (score 0):

As per jimi's comment if you want the datatable a DGV is bound to, it's still there, in the DGV's datasource:

```
DataTable dt = dgv.DataSource as DataTable;
```

If you edit a value stored in a datatable, the datatable will remember the original value. Imagine you downloaded John Smith into the first row of your datatable, with a column called "name":

```
Console.WriteLine(dt[0]["name"]); //prints John Smith

dt[0]["name"] = "Jane Doe";
```

The row now has two versions:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt[0]["name", DataRowVersion.Current]); //prints Jane Doe
Console.WriteLine(dt[0]["name", DataRowVersion.Original]); //prints John Smith
```

If you AcceptChanges on the datarow (or the entire datatable), the original is overwritten by the current:

```
dt.AcceptChanges();
Console.WriteLine(dt[0]["name", DataRowVersion.Current]); //prints Jane Doe
Console.WriteLine(dt[0]["name", DataRowVersion.Original]); //prints Jane Doe
```

---

ps; you can do away with the dataset in your helper method

```
    public DataTable GetData(string selectQuery)
    {
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, conn);
            conn.Close();

            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
```